# How to print the value of a cell if two of the excel columns match

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

[image]

I want to paste the cell value of column F if Column A and Column E match.

For instance since A2 = E3, B/2 should be the output.

What formula should I use?

Comment: `XLOOKUP`, `INDEX/MATCH`, or `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: @Scott Craner, what do you think about creating a canonical for `XLOOKUP`, `INDEX/MATCH`, `VLOOKUP` question? Not sure if one exists already.

Comment: @BigBen I think that is a good idea.  I do not have time today to do that.  Work is hammering me today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX(F2:F5,MATCH(A2:A5,E2:E5,0)),"no result")`